# how to solve AttributeError: module has no attribute python

Tags: python

I'm new to python, I have two python files in the same directory:

file1

```
import file2

file2.print_x(x)
```

file2

```
def print_x(x):
    print(x)
```

I can't understand why I'm getting this error when I run file1.py

```
AttributeError: module 'file2' has no attribute 'print'
```

Comment: What about, `from file2 import print`?

Comment: Import `print` in `file2` explicitly like `from file2 import print` which differentiates the namespaces between the inbuilt `print` and file2 `print`

Comment: If at all you address the attribute error, this program wouldn't work and will go into RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded. Because your file2 print function will be called recursively and not the print from python library. So please rename it to avoid name collision.

Comment: @NatthaphonHongcharoen NameError: name 'print' is not defined

Comment: Did you save `file2` before running `file1`? You should get `NameError: name 'x' is not defined`

Comment: If you change the name to `print_` do you still get the same error? This will let us know if the name is the problem or if there is some other issue.

Comment: @Nair code updated, sorry for the mistake of print but the error remain

Comment: @james. Good that you updated the thread. But did you update the same in your source and tried to run again ?

Comment: sorry for this stupid thing, I found in file2 the command line import file1 the removal of this line has solved my problems. I really couldn't understand why such a simple thing didn't work

Answer (score 0):

you can do `print(file2)`

you can't do `.print`
write `dir(file2)` to see all the available functions in file2